# Linq Expression to SQL text within NHibernate data context

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, expression, linq-to-nhibernate

Assuming that I have setup NHibernate data context with all relations, tables, connection etc.

How I would convert an instantiated .NET Expression (actually it's not a full SELECT but just a WHERE expression) to an SQL string?

I've seen many references. Like using ExpressionVisitor or building IQueryable Provider, but I believe NHibernate 3 has all these implementations and I just have to combine some classes to achieve the goal. Ant ideas?

Comment: Which specific version of NHibernate are you using? Last time I checked (about a 1.5 years ago), even different 3.x versions had some significant API differences.

Comment: @Cupcake I use version 3.3.1.4000. Actually I found the solution and posted the answer. Although translating the part of Expression to SQL doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, right after posting this question an approach was found here: [How can I have NHibernate only generate the SQL without executing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704462/how-can-i-have-nhibernate-only-generate-the-sql-without-executing-it).

Actually it's possible to get a text only for the full SELECT query, otherwise the exception is raised:

*Cannot parse expression '(rec.Id == 6)' as it has an unsupported type. Only query sources (that is, expressions that implement IEnumerable) and query operators can be parsed.*

Answer (score 0):

See my other answer about how to intercept sql queries by writing a custom batchers:
[NHibernate and interceptors - measuring/monitoring SQL round-trip times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321563/nhibernate-and-interceptors-measuring-monitoring-sql-round-trip-times/22323025#22323025)
It works fine for Sql Server too, once you intercept the query you are free to prevent it from executing by returning an empty result.

Comment: Hey @ReverseBlade thanks for your comment, although I am not trying to intercept nHibernate or see the queries that are being sent to DB. I just wanted to translate part of Expression query (WHERE section) to SQL text. It seems that it's impossible with nHibernate since only enumerable expressions could be translated.